# How do you change the screen background on Nexus S?

Tags: battery-life, samsung-nexus-s, wallpaper, live-wallpaper

Just bought a Samsung Nexus S. No manual came with it. Apparently the moving default screensaver eats up heaps of battery life and I am not getting much battery life out of this new phone and I am constantly recharging.

How do you change it to a non-moving image?

Comment: As the Nexus S is a "Pure Google" phone pretty much every detail of it is covered in the standard Android manual. See the Android 2.3 manual here http://www.google.com/googlephone/AndroidUsersGuide-2.3.pdf

Comment: "Screensaver"? Do you mean the Live Wallpaper?

Comment: Live wallpapers normally only consume battery when you're on the home screen, they don't play in the background.

Answer (score 3):

From the home screen, press the phone's `Menu` button. Here, there is usually a button for `Wallpaper` (it will be the top right button on the menu), where you should be able to pick your wallpaper (this applies to your background and lockscreen).

Comment: +1 You can also "long-press" on an empty bit of the home screen background and select "Wallpaper" from the menu that pops up.